# Acessar o this dentro de evento

Tags: javascript

Como posso acessar o `this` relativo ao meu objeto, quando o mesmo chama um evento? Quando o evento é chamado, o `this` passa a ser o próprio evento, o  `window.event`

Ex:

```
function Foo() {
     this.bar = function() {
        console.log('Hi!');
     }

    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        // Aqui, o "this" não é mais o objeto Foo, mas sim o "e" ou "window.event"
        this.bar();
        // Erro: this.bar não está definido... 
    }
}
```

Como posso acessar o meu objeto de dentro do `callback` do evento `keypress`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa "setar" o escopo da função anônima que o evento recebe, para fazer isso use o `.bind()`, segue exemplo:

```
function Foo() {
     this.bar = function() {
        console.log('Hi!');
     }
    //Com esse método você passa pelo parâmetro o escopo que a função tera,que no caso é this mesmo.
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        this.bar();
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando ES6 ou algum transpiler, a [*Arrow Function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) pode ser uma solução também. Elas tem o `this` do contexto que elas estão vinculadas, basicamente o contexto de onde ela foi declarada.

```js
function Foo() {
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log('Hi!');
  }
  document.onkeypress = () => { this.bar() } 
}
```

ou se precisar do parâmetro de evento`e`

```js
document.onkeypress = e => { this.bar() }
```

Gosto bastante desse approach por deixar o código mais clean